# Intercept methods in class to calculate method run time

Tags: java, interceptor

I have a use case where I am testing a workflow by invoking a series of methods in a loop. Now in order to understand the performance of my system, I am trying to calculate how much time a method takes to finish execution.

Here's a sample of how my code looks:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true) {
            String studentId = createStudent();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Runnable calls[] = new Runnable {
                () -> getStudent(studentId),
                () -> updateStudent(studentId),
                () -> delete(studentId)
            };

            for (Runnable call: calls) {
                call.run();
            }
        }

    }

    private String createStudent() {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        final long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long actualRuntime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert( endTime-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        System.out.println("createStudent :" + actualRuntime);
        return studentId;
    }

    private void getStudent(String studentId) {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        final long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long actualRuntime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert( endTime-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        System.out.println("getStudent: " + actualRuntime);
    }

    private void updateStudent(String studentId)  {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        final long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long actualRuntime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert( endTime-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        System.out.println("updatesStudent: " + actualRuntime);
    }

    private void deleteStudent(String studentId) {
        final long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        ...
        ...
        ...
        final long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        final long actualRuntime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert( endTime-startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS );
        System.out.println("deleteStudent : " + actualRuntime);
    }

}
```

Now instead of having the same piece of code being defined everywhere, I wanted to know if there's some sort of interceptor which can be introduced so as to calculate the runtime?

Also in case the interceptor is possible, I am guessing there's a workaround needed in order to identify the type of method being called/type of method for which the runtime is being calculated.

Comment: Why can't you add the time tracking to the execution loop instead?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to know which method is being called right? Like Runnable won't return the methodName of any sort. I'd have to like use Reflection to get the methodName which gets ugly.

Comment: You can create a Runnable wrapper with a method name, e.g. `new MethodExecutor("methodName", () -> methodName())`.

Comment: Just to confirm, the wrapper would extend the Runnable interface, have the methodName as a class param, and then to override the run method(), I just call the run method() on the runnable passed right?

Comment: There are several ways to do it, but that's the gist of it.